# Can't publish xUnit/NUnit test results to TFS 2010 using NUnit4TeamBuild

Tags: tfs, nunit, tfsbuild, xunit

I have an xUnit test suite written in VS 2015 and I'm trying to build the solution, run the tests and then publish the results back to TFS 2010.

It's successfully running the tests, creating the NUnit results XML, but I get exceptions when it tries to publish it back to TFS.

I'm using **NUnit for Team Build (http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/)** Version 2.0 and this is the exception I'm getting during the build:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'xUnit.net Tests'.
 File name: 'xUnit.net Tests'
 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
 at System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()
 at KWatkins.NUnitTfs.Tfs2010.Publisher2010.<>c__DisplayClassc.<UpdateTestRunWithTmiRunAndAssemblies>b__9(FileInfo file) in C:\Users\Kevin Watkins\Documents\Visual Studio 10\Projects\NUnitTFS\NUnitTFS\Tfs2010\Publisher2010.cs:line 150
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
 at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArrayTSource
 at KWatkins.NUnitTfs.Tfs2010.Publisher2010.UpdateTestRunWithTmiRunAndAssemblies(TestRun testRun, XDocument trx) in C:\Users\Kevin Watkins\Documents\Visual Studio 10\Projects\NUnitTFS\NUnitTFS\Tfs2010\Publisher2010.cs:line 149
 at KWatkins.NUnitTfs.Tfs2010.Publisher2010.PublishToTfs(XDocument trx) in C:\Users\Kevin Watkins\Documents\Visual Studio 10\Projects\NUnitTFS\NUnitTFS\Tfs2010\Publisher2010.cs:line 44
 at KWatkins.NUnitTfs.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Kevin Watkins\Documents\Visual Studio 10\Projects\NUnitTFS\NUnitTFS\Program.cs:line 29
```

**Note:** I am ***not*** Kevin Watson. I believe he's a developer of the NUnitTfs stuff and those paths in the exception aren't mine. I don't know what file it's trying to access nor why it can't find it.

If you want to look at the code/classes/line numbers that the errors are referring to, you can look at the NUnit for Team Build source code here: http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NUnitTFS/NUnitTFS/Tfs2010/Publisher2010.cs

The log doesn't show any other information, just what is displayed above.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question directly, but it's worth noting: Modern versions of TFS have a build system that can natively import NUnit test results. TFS 2010 is ancient and no longer supported. Perhaps it's time to consider an upgrade.

Comment: @DanielMann Believe me, the only reason I'm stuck using TFS 2010 is simply because I have to. I've tried suggesting an upgrade but it doesn't look like that will happen any time soon. I installed a separate instance of TFS 2015 and I can publish the test results just fine, but that's because there is no need for NUnit4TeamBuild. But I need it for TFS 2010 and I'm getting this error...